# player keeps on firing (Javascript + Canvas)

Tags: javascript, game-mechanics

I'm brand new to game development (with Javascript)... I'm pretty sure my question is very simple, but I have a hard time to figure out myself... I'm starting at the very beginning, so this is pretty simplistic.

This is my whole code in javascript:

```
var fire = false;
function keyUp(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
     case SPACE:
        fire = false;
     break;
     ...
  }
}
function keyDown(evt) {
  switch (evt.keyCode) {
     case SPACE:
        fire = true;
     break;
     ...
  }
}
function update() {
    ...
    if (fire) {
        playerHasShot = true;
        shot.x = player.x + player.w;
        shot.y = player.y + (player.h / 2);
        shot.vx += 2;
    }
    if (!fire) {
        playerHasShot = false;
    }
   ...
    shot.x += shot.vx;
   ...
    //Bullet
    if (playerHasShot) {
        playerHasShot = false;
    }
    if (!playerHasShot) {
        playerHasShot = false;
    }
    ...
    if (shot.vx > 4) {
        shot.vx = 4;
    }
    ...
    if (shot.x > canvas.width) {
        shot.x = player.x + player.w;
        shot.y = player.y + (player.h / 2);
        playerHasShot = false;
    }
    ...
    render();
    renderShot();
}
```

I hit the spacebar once, and that guy can't stop shooting... Would any of you mind telling me how to stop him, please ? I'm sure I'm close, but there's something I'm missing somewhere.... Thanks! :)

Comment: Where do you use playerHasShot?

Comment: Most of that code doesn't seem to be relevant to shooting. I would recommend you to remove all the movement- and drawing-related code from the question. The less code you post, the more people will actually bother to read it all. I, for one, lost interest after about a minute trying to find out where you actually handle shooting.

Comment: @Bàlint, It's used in the `update` function. `if (playerHasShot) {` and `if (!playerHasShot) {`...

Comment: @Philipp, I edited my code to remove the extra stuff. I thought it would be more helpful to have it all! :) Thanks!

Comment: That title is probably one of the worst and hilarious titles I've seen on gamedev.stack. I suggest you look into character controllers and statemachines. Also having 2 separate calls to render specific things '( render and renderShot ) you might want to look into writing your own little scene graph.

Comment: when and how is `fire` set?

Comment: @Brian H., I updated the code. `fire` is a boolean when the SpaceBar is hit.

Comment: Welcome to GDSE. For future reference, you should read how to make a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Back to this though, can you verify if `keyUp(evt)` ever gets called? Either fire is being set to true & never changes, or it does temporarily changed to false, but thing gets switched back to true again by mistake. Narrow the problem down to one of those two.

Comment: Please update the Question Title to more accurately reflect the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, then `fire` appears to be the flag which says if the player pressed space this frame. When that's true, and you want to spawn one bullet each time the player presses space, you need to reset that flag after spawning the bullet.

```
if (fire) {
    /* 
    ...code to spawn the projectile...
    */
    fire = false;
}
```

You won't need to do anything in case of a `keyUp` event, because releasing the spacebar isn't doing anything. That event gets interesting when you want autofire (spawining bullets while the player holds down space). In that case you would do `fire = false` in the keyup event instead of your main loop. But your code currently doesn't seem to be designed to handle more than one bullet at a time, so I don't think that this is what you want to do (at least for the moment).

I am not sure what the `playerHasShot` variable is supposed to mean in your code, because while you set and unset it various times, it doesn't seem to actually *do* anything. But I know that this section of code:

```
if (playerHasShot) {
    playerHasShot = false;
}
if (!playerHasShot) {
    playerHasShot = false;
}
```

doesn't make any sense. After the first three lines, `playerHasShot` will be `false` (or at least ["falsey"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19839952/all-falsey-values-in-javascript) if that variable can have non-boolean values), no matter what value it had before. The last 3 lines won't do anything at all. It literally means "when `playerHasShot` is falsey, set `playerHasShot` to `false`". Those 6 lines could be replace with `playerHasShot = false` and it wouldn't change anything.

Comment: you got my intent correctly. I thought I had to create a variable `playerHasShot` to be aware if the player fired or not, but I agree: It doesn't do anything...

Answer (score -1):

Did you try combining both your switch cases. And just add the keyUp and keydown together switch case,instead of having 2 different switches.